Confusion about thread synchronization
public class Interview implements Runnable {
    int b = 100;
    public synchronized void m1() throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("-----");
        b = 1000;
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
    }

    public synchronized void m2() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        b = 2000;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            m1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Interview interview = new Interview();
        Thread thread = new Thread(interview);
        thread.start();
        interview.m2();
        System.out.println(interview.b);
    }
}

When I comment out the line "System.out.println(" --");" The output is:
1000  
b = 1000   

When I don't comment out the line "System.out.println(" --");" The output is:
2000   
-----    
b = 1000    

Why is the value of interview.b different?

You have a race condition. System.out.println is sufficiently slow that m1 cannot re-assign b before the main thread prints out b. It is possible, though very unlikely that m1 will run before m2. Your possible results are ("----", "b = 1000", "2000"), ("1000", "----", "b = 1000"), ("2000", "----", "b = 1000"). You see the last one pretty consistently though because starting a thread is slow compared to just calling a method, hence m2 before m1.

It all depends on the order of execution. m1() and m2() can only run after one another but System.out.println(interview.b); can run parallely to m1().
While it cannot be guaranteed it's likely that m2() will run before the other thread spins up and starts m1() so b would have the value 2000 right before execution reaches System.out.println(interview.b);. (Why is m2() likely to run before m1()? Because creating a thread context takes some time during which m2() may have already acquired the synchronization lock so m1() has to wait. Add a Thread.sleep(1) before calling m2() and m1() is likely to start first).
And here's where the fun starts: m1() is likely to continue right when m2() releases the synchronization lock so it'll run in parallel with System.out.println(interview.b);. Without System.out.println("-----"); the first thing m1() will do is set b to 1000 which may happen before System.out.println(interview.b); which is why you see 1000 printed instead of 2000. But it you add the print statement then b = 1000 is delayed and thus System.out.println(interview.b); will still print 2000.
Let me try to illustrate.
Without System.out.println("-----");:
                        start sub thread
                        |  m2() acquires lock
                        | /     after sleeping b=2000 and then m2() releases the lock
                   main //     /  print(b) -> 1000
                   |   //     /  /
Main thread:   o---+---++-----+--+-x
Sub thread:            \++-----++----+-x
                        ||     ||     \
                       / |     |\      print("b=" + b) ->b=1000
  create thread context  |     | b=1000
  m1() starts but has to wait  \m1() acquires lock

With System.out.println("-----");:
                        start sub thread
                        |  m2() acquires lock
                        | /     after sleeping b=2000 and then m2() releases the lock
                   main //     /  print(b) -> 2000
                   |   //     /  /
Main thread:   o---+---++-----+--+-x
Sub thread:            \++-----++-+----+-x
                        ||     || |     \
                       / |     ||  \      print("b=" + b) ->b=1000
  create thread context  |     | \  b=1000
                         |     |  print("----")
  m1() starts but has to wait  \m1() acquires lock

This may sound a little vague with all the "likely", "may" etc. and that's the issue with concurrency / multithreading: parallel execution may result in different perceived order of operations (theoretically they'd happen at the same time but of course that's not true in reality - one may be faster than the other) and JVM optimizations may change some ordering as well (although the "happens before" guarantee is still maintained).

Thank you so much for your assistance.This question has been bothering me for a long time, thanks again！
